# Laravel php artisan class log does not find

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

centos7.0

laravel 5.1.11

php7.0

"php artisan"
message:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /home/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:741
Stack trace:
#0 /home/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(741): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 /home/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 /home/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 /home/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(842): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
#4 /home/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 /home/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(774): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 /home/website/vendor/ in /home/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 741
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was thrown because one of the values in the .env file may have spaces.

Just enclosed any values with space in double quotes.

For example let's assume that this is part of your `.env` file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=This Will Cause An Error

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

....
```

`APP_KEY=This Will Cause An Error` will cause this issue because it needs to be in quotes like:

`APP_KEY="This Will Work"`

Also any space after the values may cause the same issue too

Comment: I'm sure that the .env no problem , because the whole project is under the windows + php7.0 normal operation

Comment: I checked it carefully,but there is no problem.

Comment: There is a space right after null in MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null . Not sure it came with the file or you added when you're replying.

Comment: = =,I found the answer finally,the mbstring not install

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason for this error was a missing php extension. Since this missing extension raises an error, the logger tries to log it. This exception appears as a result of no 'log' class resolved from the container. I think this is a Laravel bug.

Comment: What extension was missing that is required by Laravel? I'm getting the same issue and it's not the .env file....

Comment: In my case the extension was `php70w-pdo` !! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

Check your Apache user and file system user first.
Then run the following commands to set file system permissions:

```
sudo chmod 755 storage -R
sudo chmod 755 vendor -R
sudo chmod 755 bootstrap -R
```

After you finished changing the file permissions, clean your chache with the following commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

This works for me.

Answer (score -1):

In my case i deleted bootstap/cache folder